# Prove / disprove question (just before Calculus exam!)

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

So I am going to take the final exam for Calculus I.

First, I'd love if some of you have some good questions for me to solve, or some good tips and tricks that I should notice.

Second, I have a prove/disprove question that I am trying to solve, and will appreciate your help!

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and let $L \in \mathbb{R}$.

If $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)+xf'(x)}{x}=L$, than $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{L}{2}$.

So I have a hint to define a function $g(x)=x f(x)$.

So $g'(x)=f(x)+xf'(x)$.

Also, $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)+xf'(x)}{x}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}+f'(x)=L$

I wanted to use L'Hopital's rule for $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$, but then I have noticed that I do not know if $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ even exists.

Any hints will be appreiciated!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: On your first question, literally every third or fourth question in the real-analysis section of this site will be useful for you, and they are all answered beautifully. If you are looking for answers from a specific textbook, look no further than here as well, you will find answers here. This particular question has no duplicate as I looked on Approach0 and a standard list.

Comment: Thank you so much! So just search the real-analysis tag?

Comment: It's helpful to consider derivative as the "best linear approximation" of a function, and try learning the Landau's notation.

Comment: @MathLover Yes, that is what I meant.

Comment: Hint: Take $h(x) = 2xf(x)/x^2$, and apply L'Hopital's rule to $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} h(x)$ (Note that $h(x) = 2f(x)/x$ for $x\neq 0$ ).

Answer (score 0):

Given that $$\lim \frac{g'(x)}{x}=L$$ , now assuming $f(x)\neq0$ then as $x\to\infty$ then $g(x)=xf(x)$ goes to infinity(or negative infinity) thus we can apply L'Hopital's rule , $$\lim \frac{g(x)}{\frac{x^2}2}=L\\\implies\lim \frac{2xf(x)}{x^2}=\lim \frac{2f(x)}{x}=L$$. Now if $f=0$ then the result is obvious.

Comment: I don't think that we can say that. If $f(x)=-1$ for example, than $g(x)$ goes to minus infinity...

Comment: You don't need to consider the case $f(x) = 0$ separately, L'Hospital works as long as the denominator converges to infinity: $\frac{f(x)}{x} = \frac{xf(x)}{x^2} \sim \frac{f(x)+xf'(x)}{2x} \to \frac L2$.

Comment: @MathLover We can apply L'Hopital's rule aslong as it is $\frac 0 0$, $\frac{\pm\infty}{\pm\infty}$. But yeah I mad that mistake.

Comment: @MartinR, But if $f=0$ then I can't apply L'Hopital's rule as it is $\frac 0 {\infty}$.Right?

Comment: @PNDas Yes you can, for every $\frac{\square}{\infty}$ L'Hopital works

Answer (score -1):

You can apply L'Hopital's rule backwards and integrate, given that the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)+xf'(x)}{x}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{g'(x)}{x}=L$ exists:

$$L=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\int g'(x)dx}{\int xdx}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{g(x)}{x^2/2}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{2xf(x)}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{2f(x)}{x}$$

Then, $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=\frac{L}{2}$$

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks, but I do not familiar with integrals yet :)

Comment: @TobyMak You're right. I think it's better now.

Comment: @MathLover Then just think: what gives you $x$ after differentiation? And, what gives you $g'(x)$ after differentiation? For this simple case it should be enough.